# Why is the page I am testing returning a 301 response instead of a 200 response?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-testing, django-users

I am writing tests for class-based views in the django project I am writing as part of a course. Currently, I am stuck trying trying to test a view that directs to an edit page that requires a user to be logged in. The item being edited must also have been created by that user in the first place, of course.

In the test itself, I instantiate a model and a user, and then log the user in, before trying to *get* the edit page. I expect the response to have a status code of 200, but it keeps coming back as a 301. Code below:

**urls.py - path for the edit page**:

```
path('edit/<slug:slug>/', views.EditBulletin.as_view(), name='edit'),
```

**models.py - the model being instantiated**:

```
class Bulletin(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                               related_name='bulletins')
    content = models.TextField()
    link = models.URLField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='bulletin_likes')
    edited = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

**views.py - the get method in the view for the edit page**:

```
class EditBulletin(View):
    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Bulletin.objects.filter(status=1)
        bulletin = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug, author=request.user)

        bulletin_form = BulletinForm(instance=bulletin)

        return render(
            request,
            'edit_bulletin.html',
            {
                'bulletin_form': bulletin_form,
                'bulletin': bulletin,
                'original_url_query': request.GET.get('query'),
            },
        )
```

**test_views.py - the setUpClass method and the edit page test (both within class TestViews(TestCase):)**:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.user_1 = User.objects.create_user(username='test_user',
                                          password='test')

def test_get_edit_bulletin_page(self):
    bulletin_title = 'New Bulletin'
    title_slug = slugify(bulletin_title)

    self.client.login(username=self.user_1.username,
                      password=self.user_1.password)

    bulletin = Bulletin.objects.create(title=bulletin_title,
                                       slug=title_slug,
                                       author=self.user_1,
                                       content='This is a test bulletin.',
                                       link='https://www.google.ie/',
                                       edited=False)

    response = self.client.get(f'/edit/{bulletin.slug}')

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'edit_bulletin.html')
```

I tried using self.client.force_login, and it didn't work, but I'm not sure if I was using it correctly.

I also tried unsuccessfully to initialise the many-to-many "likes" field during the instantiation of the Bulletin object, because I know that in the admin panel, I can't approve a Bulletin without providing a value for "likes", i.e. a user who has liked it. Again though, I'm not sure if I was doing it properly.

I'm confused as to why a 301 is being returned. I know that if you enter an edit url corresponding to a bulletin that you did not create, it shows a 404 page. Or, at least, with DEBUG set to True, it displays an error page.

Finally, just in case it isn't already obvious, I should add that I'm a newbie. So if there's anything really stupid jumping out at you above, please be gentle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your user you are setting the password via a text string. However, this password is hashed before it is stored in `user.password`

When you then try and login with `user.password`, which is the stored, hashed password, the password provided is hashed again before comparison. This will fail and may be causing the redirect.

Try

```
self.client.login(username=self.user_1.username,
                      password="test")
```

Comment: Just as an aside, you might also want to create your test bulletin with status=1 so it shows up in your view queryset.

Comment: These are both great answers. I feel particularly stupid about your one @SamSparx - I'm sure that leaving that out will cause problems. Will report back shortly.

Answer (score 1):

The 301 can possibly be due to the fact that the URL you are using to request the edit page does not **exactly** match the URL pattern you defined.

Your method of URL construction with string interpolation is not the best idea exactly because of these potential mistakes. Try using Django's `urls.reverse`:

```
    # test function start
    bulletin = Bulletin.objects.create(title=bulletin_title,
                                       slug=title_slug,
                                       author=self.user_1,
                                       content='This is a test bulletin.',
                                       link='https://www.google.ie/',
                                       edited=False)
    url = reverse('edit', kwargs={'slug': bulletin.slug})
    # test function assertions etc
```

This should **always** construct the same URL as you define in your `urls.py` file because under the hood, this method actually acquired the very same path you're declaring.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the url being constructed should be different, but I will use this anyway just in case, and because it seems like a good practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
urls.py
path('edit/<slug:slug>/', views.EditBulletin.as_view(), name='edit'),


test_views.py
response = self.client.get(f'/edit/{bulletin.slug}')
```

I believe this is the problem.

You defined the view url to **end** with a slash, but when you request the url in the test function, you use a url **without** a slash on the end.

Django helpfully responds with a 301 redirecting you to the correct url, **with** a slash on the end.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did actually try this already, but forgot to mention it above. I will add it together with some of the other suggestions made here though, because leaving it out may well cause issues.